# Windows 10 bluescreens and freezes

Tags: windows-10, freeze, hardware-failure, crash, bluescreenview

So I constantly get bluescreens while working with the pc and sometimes the pc also just freezes. I have

```
Windows 10 64bit
Intel Core i5-2500K, 4x 3.3Ghz
8GB (4x 2GB) RAM DDR3 Frequency 1333 MHz
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660
Asus P8H67-M EVO Motherboard
```

All drivers should be up to date - I checked them ;)

My PC is not likely to crash if I play video games. That's why I disabled power saving mode in the bios, but it didn't help at all

I collected the Bluescreens and I hope I post enough information [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/98mou4428dhsss7/CrashList.html) - 
this is a table with the crash information created by using BlueScreenView - just open it in your browser.

Unfortunatelly I cant post a table or even a html table here on superuser >.>...

Thanks for your help and I will add any information if needed!

Comment: See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. You can also upload screenshots to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Can you run stress tests such as Prime95, Unigine Heaven, and the [Microsoft diagnostics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700221.aspx) and see if any of those trigger a bluescreen?

Comment: share the real dmp files and not this useless text